# Can I add a Dynamic Field in GraphQL query?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

My static data is like below,

```
// books.json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Gullivers Travels"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Lowland"
  }
]
```

Now my typedefs are

```
// typedefs.js
import { gql } from "apollo-server";

const typeDefs = gql`
  # type book is defined
  type Book {
    id: String!
    name: String!
    fullName: String
  }

  type Query {
    getAllBooks: [Book!]!
  }  
  
`;

export { typeDefs };
```

I want to get `fullName` as an concatenation of `id` and `name` field. For example

```
    [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Gullivers Travels",
            "fullName": "1-Gullivers Travels"
    
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Lowland",
            "fullName": "2-Lowland"
          }
   ]
```

Is there any way to achieve that using *Resolvers*?
I am using [apollo-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-server) with Node JS